# Python - Get sublist of list if condition is met

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have some lists of objects I'm using in different functions for my project but first I must parse them to make sure I'm using the correct ones. I'm doing this in my function below. Currently what I'm using is a conditional check since depending on the location of the objects in the list, they might be in a different structure. I'm curious if there is anyway to consolidate the parse() function and only search in the sub list if the conditional statement is still met.

```
items = [A,[B,C,D]]

def parse(type):
    if type == 0:
        # returns A
        return items[0]
    elif type == 1:
        # returns B, C, or D
        return items[1][random.randint(0,2)]
```

to something like this...

```
items = [A,[B,C,D]]

def parse(type):
    return items[type] if type == 1: [random.randint(0,2)]
```

Comment: An array and a list are not the same thing. You are using a list.

Comment: Sorry, I will update the question.

Comment: Sry for a comment a bit cynical. I am not a native english speaker. I just reread your question around 5 times and I still have not the slightest clue as what you are trying to ask. Maybe you could try to reformulate your question entirely (in easier words and with some more context), please.

Comment: It seems like `items[type]` is what you are looking for, and you do not really need the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also pass in `items` explicitly instead of using it as a global variable. use `index` instead of `type` as that is builtin (noted by @Wyrmwood)

```
def parse(items, index):
    if isinstance(items[index], list):
        return random.choice(items[index])
    else:
        return items[index]
```

Comment: don't override builtins (type, in this case)

Answer (score 1):

```
items = [A, [B, C, D]]

def parse(items, index):
    item = items[index]
    if type(item) is not type(list()):
        return item
    else
        return item[random.randint(0, len(item))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `elif`. You're checking for one condition, and then doing a completely different thing no matter what if it isn't that condition.

```
items = [A,[B,C,D]]

def parse(type):
    if type == 0:
    # returns A
        return items[0]
    # returns B, C, or D
    return items[1][random.randint(0,2)]
```

I'm assuming this is what you meant by consolidate